# Laravel 5 How to fetch only one row of latest data for a specific user in a database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a table of drug prescriptions for all users stored. I want to fetch the latest prescription row of a defined user by id. I have tried to use the where clause and the latest method but some errors occurred as shown below.

> Object of class `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` could not be converted to a string.

```
$dispensing = Drugprescription::where('patient_id', decrypt($id))->latest();
```

The expected result was one latest row of the defined user by id.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `first()` at end the query since you want only one record for the user id.

```
$dispensing = Drugprescription::where('patient_id', decrypt($id))->latest()->first();
```

I hope you understand. You can more details on [official docs here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)

Comment: You may also need to an an orderBy('id', DESC) call in your chain to ensure you get the most recent record for the patient

Comment: @joasdioniz Please close the question by accepting this answer.